# OpenGL: How is MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE related to the real limit of SSBO size?

Tags: opengl, shader-storage-buffer

From skimming through the OpenGL documentation I kinda assumed that MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE is the actual limit on the size an SSBO might have. On my GPU this value is reported as 128 MB. However, it's working fine to create and use much larger buffers (Gigabytes), as long as they fit into video memory.

A few lines of code to clarify:
In my compute shader the buffer is accessed via

```
layout(std430, binding=2) buffer renderedDataRed
{
    uint counts_SSBO[];
};
```

On the CPU side I'm creating the buffer with

```
glGenBuffers(1, &drawBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, drawBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4 * pixelCount, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glClearBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,GL_R8,GL_RED,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,nullptr);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, drawBuffer);
```

As said, it's working fine to have pixelCounts leading to buffer sizes far beyond MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE...

So, is MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE supposed to be the actual SSBO size limit and my driver (mesa radeonsi) is just reporting wrong numbers, or did I misunderstand the documentation?
Can it be that arrays that aren't explicitly sized do not count towards MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE?

Comment: The spec says: "If the amount of storage required for any shader storage block exceeds this limit, a program will fail to link." Since you do not declare the shader storage block with a fixed size, I wouldn't know how the glsl compiler should check for this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you access the buffer after 128MB in the shader in a way that it effects the output?

Comment: Yep, the compute shader fills the buffer with data, which is rendered by  a fragment shader, and later also read back to main memory and stored to an image file. As every pixel in the image has a non-zero color, the compute shader obviously touched every single array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum storage block size is the maximum size of a storage *block*: the thing you define in GLSL that you hook a buffer object to. Since your storage block us entirely composed of a variable sized array, it has no defined size.

There is otherwise no limit on the size of the bound range for a buffer object that is bound for use as an SSBO. So as far as the OpenGL specification is concerned, this should work.

*That being said*, I would not rely on it. The Vulkan equivalent explicitly limits the size used in buffer descriptors for storage buffers. So clearly, such limitations exist.

Comment: Thanks. I'll then go with a "you can choose to try to use larger buffers, but you are on your own" setting exposed to users ;-)